# User must be on whitelist error when using Facebook Ad Insights API

Tags: facebook-marketing-api

Why does my query to the Ad Insights API result in the following response?

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/<ad_id>/insights?access_token=<access_token>&fields=...

{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#3) User must be on whitelist",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 3,
      "fbtrace_id": "..........."
   }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For testing purposes, I included every field described in the documentation, including `impressions_dummy`, which apparently causes that error.

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I too had the same problem and came here. I then removed one by one field and stumbled across the same answer. Moreover, not all fields are required for analysis, especially the ones related to 'video'

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was calling [`/adspixels`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/business/adspixels/) (to query for all pixels that are linked to an ad account) instead of the `/insights` endpoint, and getting the same error because I was querying the Pixel's `is_mta_use` field in the `fields` query param. I removed it from the list and the error was gone.